# Is there a way to convert this HQL to Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, hibernate-criteria

This is the HQL I'm trying to convert:

```
UserRequest.executeQuery("Select ur.request from UserRequest ur 
  where ur.user = :user and ur.request.type is null 
  order by ur.request.dateCreated DESC",
[user: user],
[max: params.max?: 10, offset: params.offset?: 0])
```

I tried converting it to `criteria` with the code below but it gives me an error that `No property request.type found`

```
def list = UserRequest.createCriteria().list(max: params.max?: 10, offset: params.offset?: 0) {
     eq("user", user)
     isNull(request.type)
     order("request.dateCreated", "DESC")
}
```

**Motivation for converting**

In addition to having to write a separate query to get the total (for pagination) when using HQL the other reason I want to convert it to criteria is because I'll need to filter the results of this query based on parameters. For example:

```
def list = UserRequest.createCriteria().list(max: params.max?: 10, offset: params.offset?: 0) {
     eq("user", user)
     isNull("request.type")

     if (params.filtertype == "color") 
       ilike("request.color", "%${params.filtervalue}%")
     order("request.dateCreated", "DESC")
}
```

If I try to do the above with HQL, it becomes way more cumbersome.

**Update**

Here is my class structure

```
class User {
    transient springSecurityService
    String username
    String password
}

Class Request {
    String type
}

class UserRequest implements Serializable{
    User user
    Request request

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['user', 'request']
        version false
    }

    //equals & hashcode

    static UserRequest create (User user, Request request, boolean flush = true) {
        def d = new UserRequest (user: user, request: request)
                d.save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your criteria query involves associations, try the following:

```
def list = UserRequest.createCriteria().list(max: params.max?: 10, offset: params.offset?: 0) {
     eq("user", user)
     request {
         isNull("type")
         order("dateCreated", "DESC")
     }
}
```

There's also a syntax variation that uses `createAlias()`.  You might find that easier to work with, depending on the final structure of your query.  For more examples, see the "Querying Associations" section here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria