# Why does createAlias not work on a domain that joins two domains?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I asked a question a few days back on h[ow to convert a HQL query to Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652959/is-there-a-way-to-convert-this-hql-to-criteria)

My motivation for the conversion was that I wanted to filter the results based on input from the user and the code for that in HQL would be really cumbersome. Criterias seemed like the best fit. However, I was not able to use `createAlias`.

While using `createAlias` I kept getting errors.

Here are my domain classes:

```
class User {
    String username
    String password
}
class Request {
     String type
}
class UserRequest implements Serializable{
    User user
    Request request

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['user', 'request']
        version false
    }

    //equals & hashcode

    static UserRequest create (User user, Request request, boolean flush = true) {
        def d = new UserRequest (user: user, request: request)
                d.save(flush: flush)
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm using `createAlias`

```
  def getResults (User user) {
    UserRequest.createCriteria().list() {
      createAlias("request","req")
      eq("user", user)
      eq("req.type","Test")
    }
  }
```

The complete example is on GitHub showing the problem: https://github.com/Omnipresent/createAliasTest

Comment: What error you are getting, show the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did something like this:

```
def getResults (User user) {
   UserRequest.createCriteria().list() {
     eq("user", user)
     request{
        eq("type","Test")
     }
   }
}
```

EDIT:
Check your UserRequest domain, you have:

```
Request request

static hasMany = [user: User, request: Request]
```

You have a 1:1 and a 1:N relationships between Request and UserRequest with the same name "request"

Comment: This doesn't work in my case . I get an error `duplicate association path: request` Please see https://github.com/Omnipresent/createAliasTest/blob/master/grails-app/services/createaliastest/RequestService.groovy

Comment: You have in your domain this: Request request and static hasMany = [user: User, request: Request], so you have 2 properties with the same name... do you need 2 link to Request?

Comment: I added the `hasMany` just to see whether that would fix the issue. I've removed it now but still I get the same error `duplicate association path`. I've commented out the hasMany in UserRequest: https://github.com/Omnipresent/createAliasTest/blob/master/grails-app/domain/createaliastest/UserRequest.groovy

Comment: Remove this: createAlias("request","req")